How to await a synchronous gui start using call-process?
I need some-python-qt-app to finish before running the next line.
Yet I'm unable to await until the gui is finished loading.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
(call-process "some-python-qt-app" nil 1)

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html

What's the return value of the call-process call?

Use nil instead of 1. And probably report it as  a doc bug.

Actually the doc is strictly speaking not wrong (but it can be misleading): it does not say that 1 is an acceptable value. It just so happens that any fixnum gives you the same behavior as 0. That could be clarified.

@NickD I don't know how to tell the return value. Messagebuffer states nothing particular. Using nil instead of 1 doesn't show the gui, but one of it's subsequent modal messages. i.e. the program seems running, but not visibly nor am I able to interact whatsoever. Ctrl+g kills the process.

I tried invoking sound-juicer. It is not a python Qt app, but I don't see why that should make any difference. I went to my *scratch* buffer and entered (call-process "sound-juicer" nil t). I evaluated the form with C-j. The sound-juicer GUI came up and read the CD that I had inserted, recognized it, filled in the various fields. I then pressed Extract and it started ripping the CD. In the meantime, Emacs is waiting: it's non-responsive and I get the spinning cursor. I stopped the extraction and quit sound-juicer. Emacs responded with the exit status of the process...

... 0, i.e. a normal exit with no error. Then Emacs was responsive as before. You might try with sound-juicer (or any other standard GUI program) and see if that works for you. If it does, that would more or less imply that the GUI program you are using is doing something funky, but I have no clue as to what that might be. If it doesn't work, then maybe your OS is at fault: what are you using?

Thank you for that outstanding effort @NickD <3. I'm beginning to suspect the app -at least it exit codes- as well. I'm using arch linux, spacemacs and exwm.

You can try starting it from the shell with /path/to/some-python-qt-app > /dev/null 2>/dev/null redirecting both stdout and stderr to /dev/null - that's an exact equivalent of what call-process does with the above arguments I believe.
